# Is there a way to change TestNG's output directory programmatically?

Tags: java

Is it possible to change the TestNG's output directory through java? Basically, I want to generate the reports on a different folder everytime I'm executing a script. I'm not a Maven user by the way. And I don't want to configure it through XML. I tried the following code and it is generating the report successfully but all the tests are on the `My_Test.class` and they're not displayed in TestNG's window after the execution. The output that gets displayed in TestNG's window is the gametime test.

```
@Test public void gametime(){
    TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
    testNG.setOutputDirectory("C:/temp_files/result_" + getCurrentDateTime());
    testNG.setTestClasses(new Class[] {My_Test.class});
    testNG.run();
}
```